# Как объединить все фиды моих соцсетей на одной странице?

Tags: jquery, php

Необходимо объединить все фиды моих соцсетей (Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, VK и пр.) на одной странице приблизительно так, как это реализовано на [*этом проекте*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL75P.jpg) (см. скриншот). Причем расставить их в порядке обновления по датам публикаций. Хочу поинтересоваться, сталкивались ли вы с уже **готовыми плагинами фида с соцсетей** (по хештегам или по новым публикациям, если имеются ключи)?

Извините, не могу привести собственный код, по причине того, что не знаю даже с чего начать, кроме создания ключей в соцсетях.

[image]

Comment: Товарищи, поделитесь опытом

Answer (score 1):

Ну, очевидно, что вам надо запросить у каждой API соцсети последние записи, вам выплюнется массив, допустим, на 20 объектов по каждой соцсети. Вы эти объекты приводите в соответствующий вид и кладете в свою коллекцию. Применяете к коллекции сортировку по времени и после этого рендрите на экране, как вам надо. Визуально, чтобы было плитками или как-то еще, это уже плагин надо искать.

Comment: Ну, это и впрямь очевидно) Хотелось бы узнать, может, есть готовая подобная реализация, возможно, в упрощенном виде.